# How to change UIToolbar height?

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar

I want to change the height of the UIToolbar in Navigation Controller, but I am not able to do so in swift with Xcode 7.3 and iOS 9. I have tried to set frame with CGRectMake at viewDidLoad, but it didn't work. Also tried to init a custom UIToolbar(), but the height remain the same.

**Edit:**

As per one of the answers, I have tried selected toolbar, press control and select the toolbar again, but what I got is shown in below screenshot instead:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it with ;
Change `45` for min or max heights.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    var frame = self.bounds
    frame.size.height = 45
    self.frame = frame
}

override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    var size = super.sizeThatFits(size)
    size.height = 45
    return size
}
```

Use it with like ;

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: nil, toolbarClass: Toolbar.self)
```

Thanks

Comment: May I ask where to put it? in UINavigationController? The method doesn't seems override any method from its superclass.

Comment: @victorleungtw added .

Comment: It's working perfect

Comment: @victorleungtw mate my codes working perfectly please approve my answer , thank you ;)

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 options depending on whether you are using Storyboards or not.

**Option 1: Using Storyboard**

1) Go to your Storyboard and from your selected Toolbar press and hold Ctrl and click on your Toolbar again as if you were assigning an IBAction. Then you will get the following:

(Sorry for the quality of the first image; had to take a snap with my phone because I couldn't make a screenshot while holding ctrl)

[image]
[image]

2) Then press on height to get the constraint and change the value:

[image]

**Option 2: Using Swift for e.g. 55 px height**

```
 yourToolBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height - 55, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 55)
```

Comment: Tried option 1, but couldn't open the same window as your screenshot. Mine only has options "Outlets", "Outlet Collection", "Reference Outlets" and "Reference Outlets Collections". By the way the auto layout is disabled in storyboard.

Comment: Also tried option 2, and set the frame in UINavigationController with strong reference @IBOutlet. It doesn't change either.

Comment: Yeah if you are using the storyboard you have to use option 1. Are you sure that you have selected your toolbar, then while holding ctrl you clicked on your toolbar again? It should show the blue line with the blue dots on each end. I tried this 1 minute ago and it definitely works if done right - and I have also used this in an app before

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am still not able to get the same screen as yours with xcode version 7.3.1. I edited my question with screenshot attached.

Comment: I saw your screenshot.. that's what happens when your right click the toolbar etc. Just hold Ctrl while hovering with your mouse above the toolbar and then press/click on the toolbar again. See my new attached image. As long as you don't see the two connecting blue dots, it won't work

Answer (score 1):

If you use auto layout, you could set a Height Constraint in the `Storyboard`.

Or you can do it programmatically like this:

```
myToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 35)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to mention auto layout is disabled.